# Missing dot(.) in VB 6

Tags: vb6

The code is reading from a .txt file some values, and it gets everything right. Buth when I transfer some values I need to a collection, it misses a (.) in a number, and later on makes some errors.

```
Sub readte(cFile As String)
    Dim nFile As Integer
    Dim cLinea As String
    Dim cdatos() As String
    Dim objOrd As Te

    Set coltes = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next

    nFile = FreeFile
    Open cFile For Input As #nFile

    Do While Not EOF(nFile)
        Line Input #nFile, cLinea
        ParseToArray cLinea, cdatos(), ";", True

        Set objOrd = New Te

        objOrd.cIDte = cdatos(0)
        objOrd.nProdAM2 = cdatos(8)
        objOrd.cLinete = cdatos(10)

        coltes.Add objOrd, objOrd.cIDte

    Loop

    Close #nFile

End Sub
```

The data it's supposed to get is:
cdatos(8) = 278.404

And it gives me is:
objOrd.nProdAM2 = 278404

I don't know what the error is, it's just one data that has this mistake.

I tried using Double.ParseDouble (objOrd.nProdAM2 is Double), but it says `Expected: Expression`

Comment: First of all, get rid of `On Error Resume Next`.  It will hide any runtime errors from you

Comment: So you take a number as a string, stored in `cdatos(8)`, and assign it to `nProdAM2`, which is a double. Apparently you have a locale where `.` is a thousands separator as opposed to a decimal point? Convert your data types explicitly.

Comment: @GSerg How do I change the locale? I do need it because it's a decimal point

Comment: You do not change the locale. The locale is for the user to manage. If you have numbers persisted with a decimal `.`, use functions that unconditionally use `.`, such as `Val()`.

Comment: When I use Val(cdatos(8)) it gives: nProdAM2 = 278,404 . I still need it with a dot instead of a comma. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: You seem to not understand the difference between the number and its string representation. The value stored in `nProdAM2` does not have a comma. You see comma when you print out that value with a tool that uses comma as the decimal separator. If you need to serialize that value back to a string using the dot, use a function that unconditionally uses `.`, such as `str$()`.

Comment: I used the value it gave me, and had no problem. Even if it was a (.) or a (,) I could use it as a number, and make the comparisson I needed to do. Thanks.

Comment: @GSerg if you put the answer I can give you the rep, if you want.